# How to get values from a column based on values in another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like sample DF below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id' : 
                   ['aefc6',         
                    '7edc3',
                    '6f85b',
                    '6f99b',
                    '6f85b'],
                   'user_name' : ['john', 'jack', 'jill', 'tom', 'jill'],
                   'Event' : ['A','B','C','D', 'E'],
    'Collabs' : ['adsfkj', '6f85b,asdfad', 'adfad', '9b123', '101bv']
})
```

The scenario is the `user_id`, `user_name` columns are those of event managers. But some event managers are also collaborators for some other event as can be seen in the example of "jill" who was a collaborator for Event B.

The "collabs" column is a CSV column and I unnest it as below:

```
df['new'] = df['Collabs'].str.split(',')
df = df.explode('new')
df['exist'] = df['new'].map(lambda x : x in '|'.join(df['user_id']))
```

As mentioned above, we can see that 'jill' with `user_id` 6f85b is present in the `Collab` column. My requirement is I need to get the `user_id` and `user_name` of those who appear in the `new` column or where `exist` column is `True`. I.E I need to get the ids and names of managers who acted as collaborators for other events.

Expected output:

```
    user_id user_name   Event    Collabs        new     exist   collab_user_id  collab_user_name
0   aefc6   john        A        adsfkj         adsfkj  FALSE   NaN             NaN
1   7edc3   jack        B        6f85b,asdfad   6f85b   TRUE    6f85b           jill
1   7edc3   jack        B        6f85b,asdfad   asdfad  FALSE   NaN             NaN
2   6f85b   jill        C        adfad          adfad   FALSE   NaN             NaN
3   6f99b   tom         D        9b123          9b123   FALSE   NaN             NaN
4   6f85b   jill        E        101bv          101bv   FALSE   NaN             NaN
```

I tried joining:

```
pd.merge(df, df.loc[:,['user_name', 'new']], left_on = 'user_id', right_on = 'new', how = 'left')
```

But instead of "jill" the output (understandably) is having "jack". Could someone please let me know how to get the desired output.

Comment: What should happen if you have several matches in "Collabs"?

Comment: @mozway, yes there are cases with more than one match, so when we explode or unnest the "Collabs" column, those values get their own rows and from there we need to find each such "Collabs" id in the "user_id" column. Which means that for that "Event", there've been many Managers who acted as Collaborators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isin` to create `exist` column then use `np.where` to create `collab_user_id` and map the `user_name` to `collab_user_name`

```py
df['exist'] = df['new'].isin(df['user_id'])
df['collab_user_id'] = np.where(df['exist'], df['new'], np.nan)
df['collab_user_name'] = df['collab_user_id'].map(dict(zip(df['user_id'], df['user_name'])))
```

```py
  user_id user_name Event       Collabs     new  exist collab_user_id collab_user_name
0   aefc6      john     A        adsfkj  adsfkj  False            NaN              NaN
1   7edc3      jack     B  6f85b,asdfad   6f85b   True          6f85b             jill
1   7edc3      jack     B  6f85b,asdfad  asdfad  False            NaN              NaN
2   6f85b      jill     C         adfad   adfad  False            NaN              NaN
3   6f99b       tom     D         9b123   9b123  False            NaN              NaN
4   6f85b      jill     E         101bv   101bv  False            NaN              NaN
```

Comment: Thanks!, checking with my actual data, will revert shortly.

Comment: Any particular why you went with `isin` instead of `map` method? I am new to Python just want to understand the preference

Comment: @KarthikS It's built in method and implemented in Cython so it is faster and the `join` in your `map` is redundant.